# Tcl - Creating a Sha256sum of a Tar.gz file

Tags: tcl, tar, checksum

Having difficulty getting this code to work: I have a list of files I want to archive as a tar.gz file and then create a checksum of the files

```
set chan [open myfile.tar.gz w]
zlib push gzip $chan
tar::create $chan file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt -chan
close $chan
exec sha256sum myfile.tar.gz > newfile
```

Comment: What is not working? What is the error?  More details please.

Comment: Also, which _exact_ patch release of 8.6 are you using? There have been some bugs in some parts of the `zlib` command. I think they're fixed now, and I don't remember if the compression channel filter was one of the buggy bits, but it is worthwhile double checking that.